# Change database field name manually cakephp

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp, phpmyadmin

I am working on management system build on cakephp that have two tables i.e clients and deals. client_id is primary key in clients table and foreign key in deals table. In deals table I change client_id to buyer_id now the error shows

> undefined column Deals.client_id

As I change deals.client_id to buyer_id in whole project it should work like a charm, also I am newbie to cakephp didn't know much about cakephp, is there anyway to fix it manually

Comment: You probably changed the field name in the database, but didn't change it in the code, thus the error. You also need to change the field name everywhere in the code.

Comment: I change it in code too

Comment: Did you clear the cache? If your models are cached, they can still use old version.

Comment: yes, nothing work

Comment: Please update your question with full error, including stacktrace. You can find easy to paste version in your `logs/error.log` file in your application directory.